# DirectX - CreateDeviceAndSwapChain returns E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, directx-11, graphical-programming

I'm trying to initialize Direct3D11 in C++. On machines that have Visual Studio installed(all of those are running on Windows 10), it runs fine.
On other computers (without Visual studio installed, Windows 10 and 7) it returns E_INVALIDARG.

The flag *P_FeatureLevelsSupported* says *0* on those computers. On mine it says *D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1*.
So I guess it has something to do with the DirectX installation or maybe because the SDK is missing( but wouldn't that be strange? :D )

By running dxdiag, I know that those machines support DirectX11_0.

Is there something i need to install?
The software has to run on the PCs of our clients.

The Code that causes the error:

```
const D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL lvl[] = {   D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
                                    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
                                    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
}; 
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL  P_FeatureLevelsSupported;


//see microsoft documentation, we use 11_1 or 11_0 if 11_1 is not supported by the client machine
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-initialize
result  = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, lvl, _countof(lvl), D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &swapChain, &device, &P_FeatureLevelsSupported, &deviceContext);
if(result == E_INVALIDARG) //check with FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0
      D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, 
                              D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 
                              NULL,
                              D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, 
                              &lvl[1],
                              _countof(lvl) - 1,
                              D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                              &swapChainDesc, 
                              &swapChain, 
                              &device,
                              &P_FeatureLevelsSupported, 
                              &deviceContext);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are missing a ``#ifdef _DEBUG`` guard around ``D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG``, so all your builds are forcing the use of it. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

Comment: Note that you can *also* get ``E_INVALIDARG`` if you are trying to run this program on a Windows 7 machine that lacks KB 2670838 due to the use of  ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1`` which is only 'known' by the DirectX 11.1 or better version of the runtime.

Comment: Yes that would have fixed it to. Thanks for the information about windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking to create the *debug* device by passing in `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG`. For that to succeed you must have *D3D11*SDKLayers.dll* installed which you probably have on your dev machines. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-layers) for details which includes:

> Debug Layer The debug layer provides extensive additional parameter
>   and consistency validation (such as validating shader linkage and
>   resource binding, validating parameter consistency, and reporting
>   error descriptions).
>
> To create a device that supports the debug layer, you must install the
>   DirectX SDK (to get D3D11SDKLayers.dll), and then specify the
>   D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag when calling the D3D11CreateDevice
>   function or the D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain function. If you run
>   your application with the debug layer enabled, the application will be
>   substantially slower. But, to ensure that your application is clean of
>   errors and warnings before you ship it, use the debug layer. For more
>   info, see Using the debug layer to debug apps.
>
> Note
>
> For Windows 8, to create a device that supports the debug layer,
>   install the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8 to
>   get D3D11_1SDKLayers.dll.

If you don't need a debug device when on a customer machine just remove that flag.

Comment: Thanks, thad helped, I totally overlooked it... I guess I was too focues on the feature level.

Comment: That page is missing the instructions for Windows 10: You enable the debug layer by installing the _Graphics Tools_ Feature on Demand. The SDKs don't install it.

Comment: Ah ok. So I guess you can install it with Visual Studio 2017 too... Because we did not do that on any PC